# Easier to get a high mark for an essay than a problem answer, but easier to guarantee a high mark for a problem answer than an essay?

Tags: probability

Somehow I feel that the bolded sentences below can be represented mathematically. Can it? E.g. with conditional probability?

[*Letters to a Law Student: A Guide to Studying Law at University*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1292149248). $(2017~ 4$ ed$)$. $p ~295$.

> ## Essays or problem answers?
>
> My students sometimes ask me, ‘If we have a choice in the exam between
> doing an essay or a problem question, which should we go for?’ It’s tricky.
>       I think it’s easier to write an essay that will get a high mark than a problem
> answer that will get a high mark. (I’m talking here about discursive essays,
> which are the principal kind of essays you might get asked to write in an
> exam.) The reason for this is that the general standard of essay writing among
> students is so low that an essay that is well-written, interesting and wellargued
> will be seized on by the examiner with tears of gratitude and awarded
> with a very high mark.
>       In contrast, to get a high mark for a problem answer it’s essential that you
> cover all the issues raised by the problem question and don’t make a mistake
> in discussing those issues. If you miss even one issue or misstate the law on
> one point, that will drag your mark down. So I often compare writing a
> problem answer with defusing a bomb – one false step and it’s all over. And
> when I’m marking a problem answer that has started off well, I often find
> myself holding my breath – I’m in such suspense to know if the writer is
> going to be able to get to the end of the answer without it all going horribly
> wrong. In contrast, if you make one weak argument in an essay that is otherwise
> of a high standard, the examiner will usually be indulgent and think,
> ‘Well, so what if he or she made one weak argument? The overall standard
> was so good, this should definitely get a high mark.’
>       Given that, you might think my advice to my students would be to choose
> to do an essay over a problem answer every time. But there is a downside to

$p~ 296$

> that choice. It’s this: marking an essay involves a lot more judgment on the
> part of the examiner than marking a problem answer. So if you write an essay,
> you’re always taking a bit of a chance with what mark you get for it. It may be
> that your essay is, objectively, really good – but it’s given a poor mark because
> it rubbed the examiner up the wrong way or because the examiner was in a
> bad mood when he or she marked it. In contrast, if you write a problem
> answer that covers all the issues raised by the question, does so in an
> intelligent way, doesn’t misstate the law, backs up every legal statement by
> reference to a case or a statute – you can be sure you are going to get an
> excellent mark for your answer whoever the examiner is.
>       To sum up, then: i**t’s easier to guarantee a high mark for a problem answer
> than it is for an essay – you can never be sure that an essay you write will get
> a high mark. But, on the other hand, it is easier to get a high mark for an essay
> than it is for a problem answer.**

Answer (score 1):

This goes beyond simple probability into mathematical modeling, and maybe game theory.  Here's my best attempt to model this in a simplified fashion that captures the effect of interest in a quantitative way:

Suppose that a given student has an error rate of $\epsilon\in[0,1]$ for both problems and essays, meaning that for any argument they present they have this chance of getting the argument right.  Suppose that the chance the same student's point of view expressed on an essay aligns with an examiner's is $p$.

The point the author is making is that one can write an imperfect essay and still get *lucky* and get a good essay score (because of a favorable reader), whereas with a problem, the score is simply a function of whether or not you make an error.  If a typical essay or problem involves $n$ places for errors, then the chance you get a good score can be taken in a first approximation to be

- $(1-\epsilon)^n$ for a problem (i.e. the chance you get all arguments right)
- $p$ for an essay (i.e. the chance your view aligns with the examiner's)

For fixed $\epsilon$ as $n$ gets large, the chance of getting a good score on an essay is always higher than that of a problem.  "It's easier to get a good score on an essay."  But suppose you want to *guarantee* that you do well.  Then you head to the library and study to lower your error rate $\epsilon$, and by doing so enough, for fixed $n$ you can always make your expected problem score $(1-\epsilon)^n$ greater than $p$.  "It's easier to guarantee a good score on a problem."  This is because you simply can never guarantee a good score on an essay--it just depends on the temperament of the grader, and the probability is basically fixed at $p$.

The moral here is that problems reward good students, whereas essays are basically random.  So IMO the conclusion of the author's statements is that problems are a superior way to test students (a perspective most mathematicians would probably appreciate).  However, from a game theory perspective, poor students will likely do better on essays than they would on problems, so they would strategically prefer essays.